# Problem with passing data to multiple pages in code igniter for JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Currently my team and I are working with Code Igniter 1.7.3 and we are not capable of using code igniter 2.0 with our project.

Anyway,

I made several php files in which one main files uses JQuery to load the other files inside a certain div in the main file. It goes something like this for example (They are both in the views folder in CI)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>





<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().''?>public/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){



    $("#insert-activity").load("<?php echo base_url().''?>system/application/views/bio.php");


});


</script>

<title>Title</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="insert-activity"></div>



</body>


</html>
```

Now, it loads perfectly. The problem is the controller loads the profile view

```
<?php

class UserProfile extends Controller {

    function UserProfile()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('DX_Auth');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('userprofile_m');
        $userID = $this->dx_auth->get_user_id();

        $friend_ids = $this->userprofile_m->get_friends_ids($userID);

        $data['interest'] = $this->userprofile_m->get_user_intersts($userID);
        //$data['broadcasts'] = $this->userprofile_m->get_broadcasts($userID);
        $data['friendID'] = $friend_ids;
        //$data['friendsBroadcasts'] = $this->userprofile_m->get_friends_broadcasts($userID,$friend_ids);
        $this->load->view('profile', $data);




    } ?>
```

The problem here is that I want some of the data retrieved to go to bio.php because profile.php will load the bio.php in the div.

And everytime I click on the get bio link I want it to retrieve the information again and put it in bio.php while JQuery loads bio.php in profile.php

Here is bio.php just in case

```
<!-- PHP should insert the user's bio here -->



<div id="activity-header" class="background"> <!-- activity header start DO NOT MODIFY-->

<h1>Bio</h1>

</div> <!-- activity header end DO NOT MODIFY-->



<div id="activity-feed"> <!-- activity div for JQuery  DO NOT STYLE THIS DIV-->

<div> <!-- name start -->
<div> <p <p class="special-p">Name:</p> <hr class="special-hr"> </div>
<p class="used-p">some guy</p>

</div> <!-- name end -->

<div> <!-- description start -->
<div> <p <p class="special-p">Description:</p> <hr> </div>
<p class="used-p">I don't like talking about myself... I'm emo .. for some reason</p>

</div> <!-- description end -->

<div> <!-- interests start -->
<div> <p class="special-p">Interests:</p> <hr class="special-hr2"> </div>
<p class="used-p">I am interested in:</p>

<ul>

<li>something</li>
<li>Food</li>
<li>Travel</li>
<li>Fishing</li>
<li>Pokemon</li>
<li>More Pokemon</li>
<li>POKEMOOONN!!!!</li>

</ul>

</div> <!-- interests start -->


</div> <!-- activity div for JQuery -->
```

This is the code that @kevtrout taught me. Still, the page wont load inside the div

this is the function bio inside the controller userProfile

```
function bio(){



        $this->load->library('DX_Auth');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('userprofile_m');
        $userID = $this->dx_auth->get_user_id();

        $friend_ids = $this->userprofile_m->get_friends_ids($userID);

        $data['interest'] = $this->userprofile_m->get_user_intersts($userID);
        //$data['broadcasts'] = $this->userprofile_m->get_broadcasts($userID);
        $data['friendID'] = $friend_ids;
        //$data['friendsBroadcasts'] = $this->userprofile_m->get_friends_broadcasts($userID,$friend_ids);
        $bio_view = $this->load->view('bio',$data,true);
        return $bio_view;



    }
```

And this is the JQuery inside the view  profile.php that wants to load thw view bio.php and send the data to .. This is immediatly done after the $(document).ready

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/bio');?>",{user_id: 777},function(){

        $("#insert-activity").html(data);

    },html);
```

Comment: I dont get any errors, I just dont know how to do it. Nothing is happening. I want the $data to be sent to bio.html so that when JQuery in profile.php loads it all information are there. and whenever the link is clicked, it retrieves the new information while JQuery in profile.php loads it again

Comment: Use firebug(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) - firefox addon to see what you are sending and receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
I would probably create a controller/method which loads bio information then the bio view.
then load that controller/method using your ajax.

OK, you need to add a method called get_bio or something to your UserProfile controller. The function is pretty much the same as your index function, but it loads the bio view at the end instead of the profile view.
Then change your JQuery to:

```
 $("#insert-activity").load("<?php echo site_url('userprofile/get_bio'); ?>");
```

2)
.. unless there is some reason why you really need to load the bio view using ajax, you can you just do

```
<div id="insert-activity">
     <? $this->load->view('bio'); ?>
</div>
```

because then the data would be available in the bio view.

Comment: Actually I need to use the ajax load. Because there are several links that will load several other pages in the same div

Comment: fair enough. you should do the thing I wrote in 1). You really need a controller if you're getting data from a db.

Comment: @icchanobot Thats the problem :( I'm trying to do it, but its not working the div is just empty

Comment: oh, the div is empty? I guess its because you cant ajax load a view directly in CI. You need to create a new controller method called get_bio or something and it needs to load the bio data, then load the bio view. then ajax to your_controller/get_bio

Comment: @icchanobot thats EXACTLY what I did .. But the problem is its not calling the controller :o .. and its now loading the view .. how do you call the controller?

Comment: calling `/userprofile/bio` should load your controller. try calling it directly (not using AJAX), like just type `yousite.com/userprofile/bio` in your browser.

Comment: still the same thing :( No luck

Comment: sorry, just to clarify; When you go to `/userprofile/bio` you see the bio view? but it doesnt have the data in it?  .. try typing `echo 'hello';` at the top of your bio function, does hello appear?

Comment: No, I don't see the bio view. This is what I do $("#insert-activity").load("<?php echo base_url().''?>system/application/views/bio.php"); and it shows the view.. But if i link it to controller the view doesnt load

Comment: oh yeh that wont load your controller. your jquery should be `$("#insert-activity").load("<?php echo site_url('userprofile/bio'); ?>");`. When you say it doesnt load, do you mean it has a 404? or an error? or a blank page?

Comment: inside the div .. blank page. Also I just tried $("#insert-activity").load("<?php echo site_url('userprofile/bio'); ?>"); and it didnt work .. Blank page

Comment: do you also get a blank page when you go directly to `http://yoursite.com/userprofile/bio`? And is there anything in your error logs? a blank page is often a parse error.

Comment: Yes its a blank page if I did that.. And I dont see any error in any erro logs

Comment: NVM it worked :D .. I did it .. I just erased the function and wrote it again, I guess there was something there that I didn't notice and was wrong .. Thanx for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

In your comments to @icchanbobot you stated that you are trying to use a controller to get bio information from the db and return it to the jquery script but it is not working.  I'm offering the following to try and help.  Let me know if this is the approach you are pursuing or if this is obvious to you and there is something else making the process difficult.

In my scripts, I follow the following outline when the jquery retrieves database info and injects it into the page.

```
$.post(
        "<?php echo site_url('controller_x/get_bio');?>",
        {user_id: userID},
        function(data){
            $('#insert-activity").html(data);
        },
        html
    );
```

Controller_x function get_bio() interacts with your db to pull the data out and load the view.  Using the [third parameter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) of `$this->load->view();`, I return the view html as a string and assign it to a variable, then return the variable to the [jquery post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) call.

```
class Controller_x extends Controller(){

function get_bio(){
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $this->load->model('bio_model');
    $data['bio'] = $this->bio_model->get_bio($user_id);
    $bio_view = $this->load->view('bio',$data,true);
    return $bio_view;
}
}
```

the callback function in $.post() above takes the data that was returned and injects it in the named div.  the 'html' tells the script what type of data to expect (html, json).  I believe you can get away leaving it out, but not sure without testing.

Hope this clarifies that you are either on the right track, or provides a missing detail.

Good luck.

Comment: thanx a lot, I was looking for something like this. Give me a bit of time, ill try it out and let you know :)

Comment: I tried your way, its not displaying the page inside the div still .. I edited my post above with the new code. Also, check this out, will this work if I just sent $data? http://api.jquery.com/load

Comment: NVM it worked :D .. I did it .. I just erased the function and wrote it again, I guess there was something there that I didn't notice and was wrong